# Java Heap space monitoring - are we doing it wrong?

Tags: java, java-memory-model

We have a Nagios check that checks the heap memory state on some Tomcat instances. The command it uses to get metrics back from the VM is the following:

```
java -jar /usr/java/cmdline-jmxclient-0.10.3.jar - localhost:17757 java.lang:type=Memory HeapMemoryUsage
```

Which produces output such as:

```
committed: 132579328
init: 134217728
max: 401014784
used: 18831512
```

An alert is kicked off if the value against `used` is greater than 90% of the value against `max`. This seems flawed to me, mainly because the value of `max` can go down as well as up :)

What information should we be using to monitor correctly the consumption of heap space?

Should I be comparing `max` with the value of `Xmx`?

I can retrieve the value of Xmx using the following command:

```
java -jar /usr/java/cmdline-jmxclient-0.10.3.jar - localhost:17757 java.lang:type=Runtime InputArguments
```

Is there a better way?

Comment: Even using 99% of the `Xmx` parameter wouldn't be a definite reason to raise an alarm: it might be a perfectly acceptable situation, if the next GC brings it back down (to, let's say 80% or 70%).

Comment: Can you please post the full set of flags that you use to start the process that you're trying to monitor? Rather than trying to treat a possibly-only-tangential symptom, let's have a look at the underlying...

Comment: I'm not trying to fix the process that I'm trying to monitor, I'm trying to find out if I am using the correct metrics to monitor it. I agree that even 99% consumption is not cause in itself to raise the alarm - the GC does manage to bring the value down to an acceptable value. I'm basically looking for confirmation that the current approach is wrong, that I should be comparing used against Xmx and for a better way of retrieving Xmx.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From my observations, the "max" value fluctuates. Monitoring an example Java process, the used heap varies as you'd expect, but the committed and max values also size dynamically as the used heap approaches those limits (I believe the ratios are configurable).

In my case, the Xmx flag was set to 9 GiB and strangely, the committed and max values occasionally exceeded this (9.2 GiB)?

Java tends to make aggressive use of available heap space, so a used heap size occasionally hitting 100% wouldn't bother me. Instead, I'd be more interested in the average of the last 5, 10 and 15 minutes etc. If the used heap stays above 90% for long periods, you may have a problem - checking your GC overhead would be a good indicator (and any OOME's obviously).